# In which order are async code blocks executed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Given some code like this here

```
const mainFun = async () => {
    const promise1 = asyncFun()
    const promise2 = asyncFun()
    const promise3 = asyncFun()

    await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3])
}


const asyncFun = async () => {
    // some calculation which is not async itself, and takes 1 second
    someCalculation()
    // an async call which is quite fast, let's say 1 millisecond
    await anotherAsyncFun()
    // other calculation
    otherCalculation()
}
```

and **ignoring real-world variations of run times** (edited) I would expect the execution to go something like this:

1. `promise1` started, hits its first `await` after about 1 second, looking for other code to execute while waiting
2. `promise2` started, hits its first `await` after about 1 second, looking for other code to execute while waiting
3. since `promise1`'s first `await` is done, it continues here with `otherCalculation`
4. [...]

But I can see that this depends on the implementation/runtime, e.g. that at point 3 it could be that `promise3` is started rather than going back to promise1, since we don't await any of the promises until the end. But I did some simple tests, and in those *my first intuition was wrong* (promise3 is started first).

Maybe it's kind of a question of "depth-first" and "breadth-first", but as one might already have guesses, I'm quite uncertain of what terminology to use for anything here.

So in what order is this code executed? And as a bonus: Why?

Comment: The best way to think about it is to assume it's completely unpredictable.

Comment: There's no ordering guarantee at all. You could run it a hundred times and on the last run get a different result from all the others.

Comment: If you want an order with `async` methods...it's probably best you don't use `async` methods

Comment: _“Maybe it's kind of a question of ‘depth-first’ and ‘breadth-first’, but as one might already have guesses, I’m quite uncertain of what terminology to use for anything here.”_ — Kind of; see [“run-to-completion”](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#run-to-completion).

Comment: It is a race, they might always come back in the same order, but it is not guaranteed they will.

Comment: I think some comments here miss the essence of my question. I do not rely on a specific execution order, I do not demand one, it would just be nice to know what the typical expected behavior is. If my hypothetical intentionally assumes a specific execution time to examine the behavior, I realize that this is not a realistic scenario.
I think @SebastianSimon (with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#run-to-completion) might have mentioned more of what I had in mind, although I'm not clear on what this means in async.

Comment: And to clarify again: If I say "what this means in async" I still ignore varying run times in real-world scenarios. But I guess that means the answer is "run-to-completion" (more or less the oldest task is executed first) together with how I understand the "switching" of the code execution when hitting async/await.

Answer (score 1):

What really happens is:

- `promise1` is started.
- `promise2` is started.
- `promise3` is started.
- Other code is executed until all three promises have completed.

The question "in which order are the promises executed" cannot be answered, because asynchronous operations typically involve (after the synchronous start phase) communication with other systems. Imagine that `promise1` fetches a document from a web server, `promise2` selects data from a database and `promise3` does an expensive calculation on the Node.js server itself. Then all three promises are executed on different servers, so that their executions happen independently of each other, perhaps in parallel.